# Django - rendering templates and passing them via AJAX

Tags: python, html, django, ajax, django-templates

Ok, so this a more of a conceptual question.

Basically i just found out i can do the following:
Use ajax to start a function that returns a rendered HTML template, send that as a response to ajax, then apply that HTML code to a host div. This feel so much more versatile and powerfull than using include tags.
I can render, and re-render forms (or any little snippet of HTML) in a flash with minimal JS, and, most importantly without refreshing the page.

I understand that passing whole html blocks via AJAX might not be optimal, so i am avoiding abusing this.

However this feels "hacky" to me, so my question is, Why should i NOT do this?

if you want some example code:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
<div id="formdiv1">

</div>
<script>
    function getform_rec() {
    $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "/backoffice/ajax/rec_form/",
               success: function(data)
               {
                   $("#formdiv1").html(data);
               }
             });

}
getform_rec()
</script>
```

and my view

```
def  ajax_rec_form(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        rec_id = request.GET.get("id", None)
        if not rec_id:
            form = Rec_form()
        else:
            form = Rec_form(instance=Rec.objects.get(id=rec_id))
    return render(request, "rec-form.html", {"rec_id": rec_id, "form": form})
```

rec-form.html is just a html file with no extends or includes, and it just renders the form.
Yes the view is still incomplete it doesnt handle for submission, etc.. Because i want to make sure i'm not doing somethign very bad before continuing down this path.
Oh and getform_rec() is actually beeing called by a button, i just made it call on load for simplicity here.

Answer (score 1):

You need a code like this:

```
data = loader.render_to_string(
    'rec-form.html', {"rec_id": rec_id, "form": form}
)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: i need it? why? (genuinely curious why is this better than what i got). my code is working... I just wanted to know if something is wrong with using this method